# Dismissing ViewController Scenario

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I am new to Swift programming. I am stuck in one scenario.
When my app loads, the first screen gets in ViewController1 user's latitude and longitude and then gets the data from a backend API and loads the data in a table view controller. This code of getting user's location and loading table view controller is in ViewDidLoad method. In this ViewController1, I have a button when tapped, I am presenting a view controller (Which is embedded in a navigation controller) modally. The following lines of code I am using to present this new ViewController (ViewController2).

```
let VC2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewVC2") as! NewVC2
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC2)
            VC2.delegate = self
            self.presentViewController(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When I close the ViewController2 by saying self.dismissViewController, it closes and when the control comes back to ViewController1, ViewDidLoad is executed again and all the code of invoking backend API and getting user's location is getting invoked.
So, for passing data back from ViewController2 on dismissing it, I used the delegate pattern. Created a protocol and defined a method in this protocol.

```
protocol ViewControllerClosedDelegate {
    func isViewControllerClosed(closed: Bool);
}

defined the object of delegate in ViewController2.
var delegate: ViewControllerClosedDelegate! = nil
```

and added the following code while dismissing ViewController2.

```
delegate.isViewControllerClosed(true)
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

made the ViewController1 to implement this ViewControllerClosedDelegate and added the following function.

```
func isViewControllerClosed(closed: Bool) {
        self.isFromClosedVC = closed
        print(isFromClosedVC)
    }
```

isFromClosedVC is a global variable defined ViewController1.

the value is printing correctly (true in this case) as being passed from ViewController2 when it is dismissed but when I try to print this in ViewDidLoad, it is being printed as false.
I thought of getting this value from ViewController2, and if it is true, not to execute the code to get users location and data from backend API.

Basically, I am trying to get the user's location and getting the data from  backend API once and update my table view only on Swipe to refresh.
How do I achieve this? Please help.

Thank you.
Raj

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is only called once, when the view loads. You should investigate why it's called twice… is the view controller deallocated? Are you creating a new `view`?

Comment: Hi, all I am doing is presenting view controller on VC1 and then dismissing view controller on VC2. When VC2 is dismissed, view did load on VC1 is called again. I am not sure how to check if the VC1 is being deallocated. I am not creating a new view

Comment: Are you sure you didn't use `viewDidAppear` by accident?

Comment: yes, I did not override any other method

Comment: Aaron, thank you very much, my ViewController1 is being loaded from another ViewController and this code was in ViewDidAppear in that VC. I moved it to ViewDidLoad and it fixed it. Thank you very much for your time, I really appreciate it.